# Clojure Sort-by inside macro

Tags: sorting, clojure, macros

i need to do a sort-by inside a macro,
i have a map set like this:

```
(def persons '({:id 1 :name "olle"} {:id 2 :name "anna"} {:id 3 :name "isak"} {:id 4 :name "beatrice"}))
```

if i try to do `(sort-by :name persons)` it works fine and sort it

but within the macro:

```
(defmacro select
  [columns _ map _ where _ order]
  `(sort-by ~order ~@map))
```

it doesnt sort.

REPL (clojure.core/sort-by :name persons)

Comment: And show how you were calling `select`.

Comment: I tried writing an answer, but your question is too broad right now. What do you mean by "it doesnt sort"? I would expect that with the data you show here, this would cause an arity exception. Is that the case?

Comment: i tried to compile it online and it worked.. i think its a nightcode problem
ps. https://repl.it/repls/AliceblueCloudySealion

Comment: You need to remove the `@`. Your code only works because you only have 1 entry in the `from` set. If you add any more, you're going to get an error.

Comment: @Carcigenicate when i remove it doesnt work at all.

Comment: That's because your macro is broken in other ways. To see what I was talking about, change you `from` in `select` to `#{persons persons persons}` (which should behave identically). You'll get an arity exception. Your macro isn't set up to accept a set for `from`. Your use of `@` is just temporarily hiding that bug.

Comment: Remove the `@` from the macro, and change your call to `(select [:id] from persons where [:id > 2] orderby :name)`. It should work.

Comment: The problem is we can't change the call, I'll just add a check to make sure there is only one

Comment: If your teacher is expecting that you use a set for that argument, I'll bet they're going to expect that it can accept more than 1 collection eventually. It wouldn't make sense to wrap it in a Set, and only accept a single argument. That defeats the purpose of wrapping it in the first place.

Comment: @Carcigenicateactually you were right, when the teacher calls it from an example she doesnt use a Set. Thank you for the help!
if anyone needs it this is my code right now https://repl.it/repls/AliceblueCloudySealion

Comment: Glad I could help. Make sure you understand what went wrong here though; it's an important lesson when learning macros. I actually think it's dangerous for your teacher to be having you write macros like this, since they aren't necessary, or even useful in a case like this. The fact that they're even having you use a macro here is worrying.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error in `~@map` clause. You do not need `@` here. That symbol expands a sequence in place, e.g. `[1 2 3] -> 1 2 3`.

The working code:

```
(defmacro select
  [columns _ map _ where _ order]
  `(sort-by ~order ~map))
```

Check with expanding the macro:

```
(macroexpand '(select nil nil persons nil nil nil :id))
(clojure.core/sort-by :id persons)
```